# Error from gsd-color Color Manager

Tags: gnome

I am running a brand new install of Ubuntu 18.10 under Wayland (but the same error occurs under Xorg) on a brand new laptop. I use  about 15 Gnome extensions. In my logs I get the "important" warning `Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop`I have nailed the error down to this line in syslog:

> failed to connect to device: Failed to connect to missing device
>   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_AU_Optronics_gdm_123

What is this error referring to? I have no symptoms or problems with the setup other than this error message.

Comment: This appears to have been an issue for years. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/265